# Sequelize: Many-To-Many relation between MariaDB and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, sequelize.js

**Little Background Story**
Here is my scenario, I have a database named `Location` in my MariaDB, and I have a `User` database in my Postgres. I want to chain two of them in my Postgres DB. So I have two tables `users` and `userLocations`. Oh yeah, a nice thing to note is that **I only have access to read (SELECT and CREATE VIEW)** from `LocationDB`, and connecting to `UserDB` as root. Yes I have successfully `authenticate()` both of them. I even able to receive data from `LocationDB` however the only problem right now is creating that relation between `User` and `Location`. Error logs available on the bottom.

Here is my models:
`models/user.js`

```
// ... Connection to UserDB (uses Postgres)
const UserDB = require('../datasources/user-db')

const User = UserDB.define('user', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }
})
module.exports = User
```

`models/location.js`

```
// Connection to LocationDB (uses MariaDB)
const LocationDB = require('../datasources/location-db')

const Location = LocationDB.define('ms_location', {
  id_Location: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
  name_Location: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }
}, { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true })
module.exports = Location
```

`models/user-location.js`

```
// ... Connection to UserDB (uses Postgres)
const UserDB = require('../datasources/user-db')

const UserLocation = UserDB.define('userLocation', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }
})
module.exports = UserLocation
```

`app.js`

```
const Location = require('./models/location')
const User     = require('./models/user')
const UserLocation = require('./models/user-location')

User.belongsToMany(Location, { through: UserLocation })
```

*This is a minified version of the case, if you need more information please do ask as I am still new to `sequelize` as well*

The error log: (sorry I don't have any idea to beautify it)

```
{ SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "ms_location" does not exist
    at Query.formatError (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/sequelize/5.8.6/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:354:16)
    at query.catch.err (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/sequelize/5.8.6/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:71:18)
    at tryCatcher (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:517:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:574:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:695:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/3.5.5/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent:
   { error: relation "ms_location" does not exist
       at Connection.parseE (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/pg/7.11.0/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:602:11)
       at Connection.parseMessage (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/pg/7.11.0/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:399:19)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/pg/7.11.0/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
     name: 'error',
     length: 107,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42P01',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: undefined,
     position: undefined,
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: 'namespace.c',
     line: '426',
     routine: 'RangeVarGetRelidExtended',
     sql:
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "userLocations" ("id"  SERIAL , "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "userId" INTEGER REFERENCES "users" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "msLocationIdLocation" INTEGER REFERENCES "ms_location" ("id_Location") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, UNIQUE ("userId", "msLocationIdLocation"), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));' },
  original:
   { error: relation "ms_location" does not exist
       at Connection.parseE (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/pg/7.11.0/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:602:11)
       at Connection.parseMessage (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/pg/7.11.0/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:399:19)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (<path-to-project>/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/pg/7.11.0/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
       at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
     name: 'error',
     length: 107,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42P01',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: undefined,
     position: undefined,
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: 'namespace.c',
     line: '426',
     routine: 'RangeVarGetRelidExtended',
     sql:
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "userLocations" ("id"  SERIAL , "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "userId" INTEGER REFERENCES "users" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "msLocationIdLocation" INTEGER REFERENCES "ms_location" ("id_Location") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, UNIQUE ("userId", "msLocationIdLocation"), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));' },
  sql:
   'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "userLocations" ("id"  SERIAL , "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "userId" INTEGER REFERENCES "users" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, "msLocationIdLocation" INTEGER REFERENCES "ms_location" ("id_Location") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, UNIQUE ("userId", "msLocationIdLocation"), PRIMARY KEY ("id"));' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've told Sequelize that you have a table called `user` and a table called `msLocation` and that the two are related through another table called `userLocation`. (Or is it `userLocations`? Your code and error message are inconsistent.)

It looks like Sequelize is trying to create the `userLocations` table `UserDB` but it's failing because as part of the table definition, it's trying to create a foreign key reference to ms_location:

```
"msLocationIdLocation" INTEGER REFERENCES "ms_location" ("id_Location")
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

which fails because ms_location is not in the `UserDB` but rather in the other database.

I don't know if Sequelize can actually handle tables spanning multiple databases servers, but I doubt it. Creating a query that spans two tables in the same database is easy, Sequelize can just create a join. It's a totally different story if the tables are on two different servers; now Sequelize would have to run two different queries and do all the join logic in memory. That's a pretty big lift.

Some databases have a way to create a table in one database that replicates or forwards to a table in another database. If PostgreSQL supports that, you could try using that to replicate or shadow the MariaDB table, which would enable Sequelize to see all the tables as being part of `UserDB`.

Comment: Ah I see! I thought it would just left the `userLocations` table with the location's `id_Location` cause that's the only thing I wanted to do. Also, I think the error message isn't inconsistent, because I think it's one of Sequelize feature to add `s` to all table names. I have `user` table and it becomes `users` in the database.